# Memory and speed issues when single and double matrix get involved simultaneously in Matlab

Tags: matlab, casting

If A is a n by n double matrix and B is a n by n single matrix (n is large), we want compute A*B. I know the resulting matrix is type of single. My concern is

1) Will Matlab implicitly create a temporal single matrix to store the values of A?  Or, does this kind of mixed-type computation entail larger memory usage?

2) Is this mixed-type computation slower than homo-type computation? Or, does this kind of mixed-type computation slow down the program?

Should we try to do computation using homo-type data explicitly? I believe if we know how Matlab exactly work, we can predict our code's behavior more accurately. This must be helpful.

Comment: You can try to time it.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes, I can do that. But my test must be special and has many limits. The reason why I asked here is I wander if someone know the internal mechanism of Matlab. It's more accurate and helpful if we know how Matlab really work.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with Ander and proceed with timing to validate any claim about what to prefer (single or double precision). Here is an example for benchmarking the two approaches:

```
   N = 1e3;
   A1 = single(rand(N,N));
   A2 = double(rand(N,N));
   B = double(rand(N,N));
```

Now we can proceed to timing the two approaches. I usually do multiple repetitions of the same calculation (here I do it 100 times):

```
    tic; for ii = 1: 100 ; C1 = A1 * B; end; toc % mixed single and double
    Elapsed time is 0.600353 seconds.
    tic; for ii = 1: 100 ; C2 = A2 * B; end; toc % both doubles
    Elapsed time is 1.500283 seconds.
```

So it seems that when A is single precision (A1) it is twice as fast.

Comment: I'd say yes if we don't have other options. But I still prefer to know the internal mechanism to predict the code's behavior accurately:-( I did tests for other problems before and the test results really varied a lot from time to time.